# NativeScript Firebase onMessageReceivedCallback does not fire on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, nativescript

I am using NativeScript-Vue (7.0) and using this code to initialize Firebase:

```
firebase.init({
        onMessageReceivedCallback: (message) => {
          console.log("[Firebase] onMessageReceivedCallback:", { message });
        },
        onPushTokenReceivedCallback: (token) => {
          console.log("[Firebase] onPushTokenReceivedCallback:", { token });
        },
      })
      .then(() => console.log("Firebase initialised."));
```

Everything works fine on Android, but on iOS (on simulator as well as on a real device) two things are happening:

1. `onPushTokenReceivedCallback` is fired TWICE (with same token)
2. `onMessageReceivedCallback` is never fired even when app is in foreground.

I am using FCM Dashboard to send notifications, tried both `Test` as well as `Campaign` notification with custom data. It only worked in Android.

I understand there are complications in implementing background push notifications in iOS but in foreground when app is running, why isn't it receiving the message?

I am using this [firebase plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase) and I followed everything in the docs apart from one thing that is `Enabling push support in Xcode` as apparently this setting is gone from Xcode for free apple developer accounts. But I did add the entitlements manually as mentioned [here](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/MESSAGING.md).

Does receiving message call back require some special permission or am I missing out on something?

Comment: any luck? I am facing a similar issue except I'm finding both callbacks are called twice

Comment: @NickWiltshire yup I solved the issue. The problem in my case was APNs was not configured with FCM. Read this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs | Also, for generating these certs/keys I upgraded to paid Apple Developer account. After generating the AUTH keys, you need to go to `Project Settings` > `Cloud Messaging` to upload/set the keys. Plus, you need a real iOS device (not emulator) to send a background push.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I think you will have to enable the Push Notification capability in XCode.

Once you do that, if you are using `@nativescript/ios: 7+` and `@nativescript/firebase: 11.0.0` when you do get foreground notifications working, the app will crash. To get around this we had to use `@nativescript/ios: "6.5.3" (this uses the original JSC iOS runtime rather than the new V8 iOS runtime) which resolved the app crashes for us.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the answer, will try this approach and report back.